# FTP server running on Port 2000 over NAT not working on Passive Mode

Tags: ftp, port, portforwarding, nat, passive-mode

I am running FILE-Zilla ftp server on windows in one of the LAN pc connect to my router. i am trying to access the FTP server from the network outside of the router using Router WAN ip **(WAN-to-LAN)** by adding Port-Forwarding rule **(NAT)** in the router. I have 2 cases here as per below configurations. the ***1st is working*** and the ***2nd is not*** (in Passive mode).

> Note: i have added the custom inbound rule in the windows 7 firewall
>   where the ftp server is running.

**Configuration #1**

```
Filezilla FTP server port: 21
Passive port range: 50000-51000

NAT - external port: 21
NAT - internal port: 21

Windows firewall inboud rule port allow port: 21, 50000-51000

Client connecting to: <Wan IP>:21
```

**This is working if client is trying to connect using Active/Passive mode**

**Configuration #2**

```
Filezilla FTP server port: 2000
Passive port range: 50000-51000

NAT - external port: 21
NAT - internal port: 2000

Windows firewall inboud rule port allow port: 2000, 50000-51000

Client connecting to: <Wan IP>:21
```

This is working only if client is set to *Active mode*. 
**Not working with Passive mode** configuration by client. the client can connect and login is successfull but ends with the error message at server side like this without any directory listing.

```
227 Entering Passive Mode (192,168,1,2,195,85)
```

> Note: both the case working in LAN-LAN network.

Comment: Does the configuration #1 work, if you use TLS/SSL?

Comment: What FTP client are you using for the test?

Comment: #1 always working without TLS/SSL.

I am not using the TLS/SSL feature here, it's unchecked. `(000064)28/2/2017 15:44:29 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.2)> AUTH TLS
(000064)28/2/2017 15:44:29 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.2)> 502 SSL/TLS authentication not allowed
(000064)28/2/2017 15:44:29 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.2)> AUTH SSL
(000064)28/2/2017 15:44:29 PM - (not logged in) (192.168.1.2)> 502 SSL/TLS authentication not allowed `

Comment: So please enable it and test it.

Comment: Using mobile client AndFTP for Android.

Comment: Include a client log file for both scenarios (use a PC client, if you cannot get a log from the AndFTP).

Comment: Where to get the certificate files to enable the TLS/SSL feature?

Comment: There's the "Generate new certificate" button.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136841/discussion-between-amit-shah-and-martin-prikryl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that the configuration #1 works only because the NAT is smart enough to translate the IP address in the `PASV` response from the server. But it likely does that only for the standard FTP port.

---

You should tell the FileZilla FTP server its external IP address. Go to *Edit > Settings > Passive mode settings > IPv4 specific > External Server IP Address for passive mode transfers*.

Currently your FTP server is sending its internal IP address to the client. And the client obviously cannot connect to the IP address.

And have the NAT forward the ports in the passive port range (50000-51000).

---

Though the change will break the LAN-LAN connections. To allow both LAN and WAN connections, check if the NAT can be configured to translate the IP address for the non standard ports too. Though the translation will work for unencrypted connection only anyway. And you should not use unencrypted connections!

The last option is to use the extended passive mode (`EPSV`), if your clients allow that. In the extended passive mode, there's no IP address in the response. The FTP client uses the primary IP address of the FTP server for data connections.

Comment: 192.168.10.84 is WAN ip, and 192.168.1.2 is LAN so should i give 192.168.10.84 in the settings `Edit > Settings > Passive mode settings > IPv4 specific > External Server IP Address`

I will try first this and then the TLS/SSL. give me some time..